# Ruby on Rails, Connecting Each() Directly to Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, each

In ruby is it anything more than a personal preference and readability issue whether i code something like

```
 My_Table.all().each{ DO SOMETHING }
```

As opposed to

```
table_info = My_Table.all()
table_info.each { DO SOMETHING }
```

EDIT: code added that prompted me to ask this question.

```
games = Game.where(league: Team.leagues[league])
           .where(final: true)
           .where(part_of_season: part_of_season)
           .pluck(*fields).each_with_object({}) do |row, hsh|
             hsh[row[0]] = Hash[fields[1, fields.length].zip(row[1, row.length])]
           end
```

Comment: What are you doing that you need to use `#each` immediately upon grabbing the table information? There may be a better solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> In ruby is it anything more than a personal preference and readability
>   issue whether i code something like

no

BONUS:

if league is properly modeled, you can simplify it:

```
finals = league.games.where(final: true, part_of_season: part_of_season)
```

Answer (score 0):

personally I would use a named scope

```
class Game
  scope :games_for_league, lambda {|leagues, part_of_season|
    .where(league: leagues, final: true, part_of_season: part_of_season)
  }
end
```

and then on your controller

```
leagues = Team.leagues[league]
games = Game.games_for_league(leagues,part_of_season)
            .pluck(*fields).each_with_object({}) do |row, hsh|
               hsh[row[0]] = Hash[fields[1, fields.length].zip(row[1, row.length])]
             end
```

I'm not sure what you are doing with that pluck but you could move that too to a scope

```
leagues = Team.leagues[league]
games = Game.games_for_league(leagues,part_of_season).another_scope_with_that_pluck
```

Always try to move logic and queries to your models, it makes controller specs reaaaaally easier and the code look so much clean